# Replacing a string containing a question mark

Tags: regex, perl

This is my code:

```
$html = 'Is this a question? Maybe.';
$old = 'question?';
$new = 'reply?';

$html =~ s/$old/$new/g;
print $html; exit;
```

Output is:

```
Is this a reply?? Maybe.
```

Desired output:

```
Is this a reply? Maybe.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [quotemeta](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) to escape the `?`:

```
$html = 'Is this a question? Maybe.';
$old = quotemeta 'question?';
$new = 'reply?';

$html =~ s/$old/$new/g;
print $html; exit;
```

Answer (score 6):

In regexes, the question mark is an operator meaning *one or none*. Therefore, we have to escape it:

```
s/question\?/reply?/g
```

Note that it isn't special in strings. Because interpolating random strings into regexes can have such unwanted effects, you should `quotemeta` them first.

- Either by using the `quotemeta` function: `$old = quotemeta "question?"`
- Or by using a `\Q...\E` region in the regex:

  ```
  s/\Q$old\E/$new/g
  ```

Answer (score 2):

`?` has a special meaning in regular expressions.  You just need to escape it in your pattern:

```
$old = 'question\?';
```